# Are postgres UUID numbers homogeneously random?

Tags: random, uuid, entropy

Looking at UUIDs generated as primary keys by Postgres defined by RFC 4122, ISO/IEC 9834-8:2005 (source http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html). Can we consider that these numbers are homogeneously random on all their length ?

Given this UUID :

`a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11`

Can we objectively assume that `a0eebc99` and `bd380a11` are equally as random ? If not, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUIDs in general are meant and optimized to be unique. They do not offer a guaranteed randomness. You should not use UUIDs as secrets and/or random number generator.

There are several versions how UUIDs are generated, most of them are not random, but rather predictable. See the [Wikipedia article on UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and the various versions.

If you want to avoid collisions for IDs, use UUIDs, if you want secrets, use strong cryptographic (P)RNGs.

Also note, that the variant is encoded in the UUID itself, so at least this part of the UUID is *not* random at all.

EDIT: There is an interesting [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160606150425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553) by Raymond Chen in his famous blog "Old New Thing" about almost exactly this question.

Comment: I understand. Your answer perfectly answers the question but maybe my question was not clear. Does that means the 8 first digits and the 8 last digits of the whole UUID have the same probability to encounter a collision on their respective part ?

Comment: Actually there is a very good article by Raymond Chen about exactly this question: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553

Comment: Blog has been moved, here is a valid archive.org link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160606150425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553